# Why do I see two jobs in Spark UI for a single read?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-ui

I am trying to run the below script to load file with 24k records. Is there any reason why I am seeing two jobs for single load in Spark UI.

code

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .appName("DM")\
    .getOrCreate()


trades_df = spark.read.format("csv")\
    .option("header", "true")\
    .option("inferSchema", "true")\
    .load("s3://bucket/source.csv")
```

trades_df.rdd.numPartitions() is 1

[Spark UI Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HdNM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because spark reads the csv file two times since you enabled inferSchema.

Read the comments for the function `def csv(csvDataset: Dataset[String]): DataFrame` on spark's github repo [here](https://github.com/jerryshao/apache-spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.scala#L470).